# Maintaining same session accross Angular2 and Spring Applications

Tags: spring, spring-security, angular2-routing, typescript2.0

I have a Spring + JSF based web application currently running. We are planning to migrate it in Angular 2 with Typescript module by module.

How can I achieve integration of session state between the two web applications? User will sign in only once. Depending upon the module he selects, he will be redirected to Spring or Angular app.

Comment: Hmm, you could stay with the login page 'as it is'. On success will redirect to proper module (index.html angular bootstrap) with all session related headers and will work in old way - including ajax requests by angular services

Comment: You mean I need to pass all session data from spring application to angular application? How can I do that? I am very new to such cross platform session management.

Comment: I could finally achieve this by using session storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using session storage. Once you login to spring application, make a call to token store with username and password. This will give you access and refresh tokens back as a JSON response. Store that in session storage. Use the same tokens to login to angular.

Its working fine for me.